# save web page login credentials via webview in android storage

Tags: android, caching, cookies, authentication, webview

*Basically I just have like 6/7 months of experience with Java, and 2/3 months of experience with Android...*

I was asked, while in my internship, to develop a simple Android app that allow access to an existing (and working) responsive web page.

The idea is simple:

> - the page works with a login in order to access certain content;
> - the objective is that the user only needs to login just once;
> - the login credentials are to be saved locally in order for the user to be automatically logged in next time the Android app is accessed.

I understand concepts of session in web development, as well as working with PHP and JavaScript.

Now in Android I only know how to do this separatelly from a webpage (login activity, saving credentials to SharedPreferences, etc), but this is not what my employers want...

I'm a little bit lost, because CookieManager was deprecated, as well as a series of other WebView methods...

**The app only needs to start the MainActivity with a WebView as only child view of the main layout (e.g., a FrameLayout), and then everything else must be managed in the webpage...**

How can I do this? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as no other solution was found, I stored encrypted values on sharedPreferences, then read them, decrypt, validate, and send to the server, and handle any response from it while opening the webView.